# Create a non editable attribute in Excel cells that is still readable for a c# program

Tags: c#, excel

I have a very particular problem. I looked for similar problem to mine, test a lot of solution everyone proposed, but none of them is what I need.

My client need to export data sheet in excel format. Those data can be sorted, modified, rearranged, new values can be entered, some lines may disappear, some other can take their places, in short, anything can happen to those data. For example purpose, let's say that we export a list of item shown in a grocery list.

```
ItemID ItemName Price
Fr01   Apple    2.5
Fr02   Orange   4.0
Mt01   Beef     10.0
Mt02   Pork     8.33
Vg01   Carrot   1.25
```

My problem is that this data can be imported back in the software that originally created the excel to update (or add) these values in database base on the "ItemID". I already do validation if data is "correct" in value and type and interrelationality.

I tried to put a name to the range. The problem is when data is filter / sorted, the name don't follow the content, it stand still at the same position

original : (Range name is the name of the range, not an actual column)

```
ItemID ItemName Price || Range Name
Fr01   Apple    2.5   || data_fr01
Fr02   Orange   4.0   || data_fr02
Mt01   Beef     10.0  || data_mt01
Mt02   Pork     8.33  || data_tm02
Vg01   Carrot   1.25  || data_vg01
```

after sorting on ItemName:

```
ItemID ItemName Price || Range Name
Fr01   Apple    2.5   || data_fr01
Mt01   Beef     10.0  || data_fr02
Vg01   Carrot   1.25  || data_mt01
Mt02   Pork     8.33  || data_tm02
Fr02   Orange   4.0   || data_vg01
```

As you can see, all the info correctly follow, except the Range Name, so, when I try to import, I got a lot of data mismatch.

My other try was to make the NameRange an actual cell in excel. With this method, the cell follow, but can be changed, so I try to create a protected cell. Sadly, lines can't be inserted or deleted because of that. I found a workaround that consist in having names in a masked sheet, but once again, I need to synchronize sheets, which is not reliable for the same reasons mention previously.

Even worst, I must support both xls (97-2003) and xlsx.

So I'm looking for a stable workaround that will allow me to store somehow my "range name" data in the cell, making it invisible for the Excel User, but will follow the data so i can retrieve it at the right place when re-importing data.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT :

At finale, I must be able to write this property from C# application and then read back that same property with C#, and it must be compatible both excel file format, not viewable nor editable by excel user but stay with it's original value set, whatever happen to the data within the sheet except deletion (I don't mind if I just put it on the cell I wrote Apple in and not the entire range)

Comment: this happens when your sort does not include the `Range Name` column. Simply include it and they will move with the other data in that row as a unit.

Comment: Range Name is not a column. I just put it here to be able to see the result, but range name is the "Name of the range" hidden somewhere in excel define as "Range['data_fr01']:{B1:B3}"

Comment: ah I though you were trying to tag your rows. In that case how are you using the Named Ranges? What does the order have to do with your import?

Comment: I think Miraino is saying that named ranges on sorted data remain static, i.e, if data_vg01 refers to cells B1:B3, then if a sort moves the data that was in cells B1:D1 to, say, B5:D5, the range *name* - not the label of the name - still refers to cells B1:D1. That given, he's asking for a good way to hide the label of the name from users.

Comment: @chuff That's exactly it. Finding a way to hide it from user but still be able to use it with the right data attached to it. 
_By the way, name is Hikari. I just don't know why I still mark them reverse way. ;)_

Comment: If you allow randon changes to this data (including allowing users who may not be Excel-savvy to add new records, filter and sort rows) then without some really strict controls this seems like a recipe (no pun intended) for disaster.  It only takes one user to mis-sort the data (eg excluding one of the columns in the sort) and your whole database could be corrupted...

Comment: I agree with @TimWilliams, you can't ever expect your users to follow convention, you have to force them to use the application the way that you intended. Perhaps using excel spreadsheets isn't the best way to go about this

Comment: I know. And at least, there is a sort of control back in my software to prevent total annihilation of my database (first step is to not import directly in the database, but having a validation report and a data backup before updating / adding data to database). But I try to prevent this kind of mismatch by, at least, having the primary key not in the possible "destroyable" values.
It's not my decision to have the spreadsheet. If the decision was mine, the user only use the software and never excel again, but it's a Client spec.

Comment: Why isn't the `ItemID` and the `ItemName` enough for your C# program to figure out what the data_key should be?

Comment: @RBarryYoung It was an example, but in fact, no. The ItemID is like a serial number generate from other properties and can sometimes change a little. ItemName is only a descriptive that can be widely changed. Globaly, my real object has around 26 properties, and sometimes 1 or 2 that can't change, but it's not enough to recognize them (example : vg05 - tomato that will become fr05 - red tomato for some obscure reasons) because of that, i can't know if it's a new item or an updated one, and with the validation, may occure to be dupplicated and not be considered at all.

Comment: @MirainoHikari Then why can't you just add another column to hold the data_key?

Comment: It was my temporary solution. But we need to avoid them to edit sensible data. But I may I found a workaround using a hidden column comment and locking the comment edition in excel. Need to do some test about it since I don't quite know how xls and xlsx format will give me the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a little of everyone suggestion and merge them.

Since any simple and normal solution isn't viable in our context and since the only possible property we can try to put something in (ID) isn't persistent and with the fact we need the client not to accidentally destroy the value considering the fact that anything may happen and will happen since there is no much restriction and the fact that we can't lock a part of the sheet without disabling line manipulation because of the side effect of the presence of a locked cell, the closest thing we were able to achieve was to insert our keys as a formatted string in column A with a weird looking formula allowing us to hide from display, then we hide the column, making it unreachable accidentally by the user.

```
=IF(FALSE,"our formatted string","")
```

Since this hidden column has data, it follows its line when sorted and trying to copy the entire line won't be possible with the fact that we select only from column B (which cause to try to insert 256 values in 255 cells) we can control a little the "false duplicate", even if not totally eliminated.

On the importer side, we just read back with a little trick comparing the formula with the value (since value is empty, only formula got our formatted data) and having a little regex to retrieve the meaning of our formatted string then doing all our validations before the actual database import.

For the rest, it will go to the training part of the user to not "delete" the data in column A, and not searching for it.

Thanks again to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

OK (I still think its better to add validation intelligence to the worksheet when you export but YMMV).

Try using the Range.ID string property - its not editable or visible from the Excel UI and it moves around with the cell. If the cell gets deleted it disappears. If a cell gets copied the ID property gets copied so there would be a duplicate.

It was introduced in Excel 2000 so probably won't work for Excel 97 but should be OK in all file formats for Excel 2000 to Excel 2013. 
Here is some example VBA code:

```
Sub putids()
    Dim j As Long
    For j = 1 To 5
        Range("a1").Offset(j - 1, 0).ID = CStr(j)
    Next j
End Sub

Sub getids()
    Dim j As Long
    For j = 1 To 5
        Debug.Print Range("a1").Offset(j - 1, 0).ID
    Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: For the validation, as I said, it's already done in the data importer.
For the rest of your solution, it's pretty it. I'm going to test this possibility very much since it's very very close to what we need. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I got a little problem with your solution. ID don't seems to survive to save. When I save my worksheet and reopen it, all my ids went off. Do you know why?

Comment: As I see on an answer you give on MSDN, is this possible to add a CustomXMLParts to those files or it won't work because I need to support old xls file format?

Comment: You are right - ID does not persist (I had not thought through your requirememt). Solving the persistence problem is a whole new discussion: some options are 1) Defined Names (small amounts of data) 2) Hidden worksheets 3) Custom XML parts (but not .xls) 4) Associated data files (fragile) 5) Binary Names (needs XLL interface) - but in all these solutions you need code in the workbook or in an addin to retrieve the data at workbook open time etc

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use some key column be it a unique name you've made up, a concatenation of the records making up your data row. Whatever. Make that as the left most column, hide it and lock it do users can't show that column or change it's contents.

Then in another worksheet, take those same values and starting in A2 paste them in.

Now in B2 enter this formula

```
=VLOOKUP(<this row's key value>,<Your data array in sheet1>,<column number>,FALSE)
```

Here is an example of how to so the fixed column/row settings

```
=VLOOKUP($A2,BigNamedRange,B$1,FALSE)
```

now Hide that sheet.

Now what you have in the first sheet is an area where your users can filter/sort/do whatever and in your second, controlled sheet, you have the data in the order you want to see it (which can be changed independently from the user's sheet).

Edit:

Click on 1: `Allow Users TO Edit Ranges` and set the range you want to let users edit.
Then, 2:, click `Protect Sheet`/`Protect Workbook` (which ever you need) to lock everything else.

Now your users can edit what you let them and not edit everything else 
[image]

Comment: The fact is that my data contains my database primary key. It can't be made of some values of my data. And as mentioned, I can't lock a column since it block the delete / insert line possibility. And since user can edit the data, my "generated key" may be totally different that way

Comment: well then, by all means, use your DB's key. it's perfect for this.

Comment: that's exactly what I do, the problem is the "not editable - hide to user - still usable in my import with correct data" thing. :(

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't work the way I need it to. Plus the fact that it's always possible to unlock, and it's not a real excel with full control since it's generated from another software, not excel itself. But more over, locking cells disallow any modification interacting with the entire row (like delete). I really need something more like "Range Name" or "Cell Property". Actualy, I can generate hidden RangeName, but still have the same probleme as visible RangeName.... they don't follow their data

Comment: It's pretty impossible to unlock an Excel sheet. Just don't give them the password. How is the Excel generated? Are you using Interop, EPPlus, ExcelLibrary? I'm pretty sure you can protect sheets from all of these. Unless it's not in your control then you're just going to have to handle this through user training

Comment: Yeah, but it must not protect it, since they can delete lines... Created via reflective com. Yeah, I can lock the sheet, but i mustn't since user need "full control. That's the why of my problem. They are in transition mode. Some of them still use their excel, and some other already use the soft (at least I hope). But maybe, as you say, the only solution will be user training and still adding my pk in a cell and say them not to erease it... anyway, my validator verify for duplicate and forbid duplicate entries in database. Thanks anyway for your help

Comment: what we do in these kinds of scenarios sometimes is lock down the sheet. Restrict user input/changes to data validated lists. If they want to "delete" a row use a drop-down that says "Use"/"Do not Use". We usually, in a hidden column create a `union select` for all the data in that row for quick loading into a temp table via copy paste. than you can do additional validation. But we only work with one person at a time. Not sure how many files you have coming in. But definitely like Charles says, Data validation with conditional formatting is your friend.

Comment: ...Conditional formatting especially, then you can call out errors to your user in bright colors before they hit save.

Comment: Already the case. And files can be "spreded away" (I have to make a conflict change check when importing) and in the software side, make the checks that validate everything need to be validate and already have a colorfull display and a check box within my listview to allow import or not... the only remaining step, is to hide the pk from the excel but still be able to use it.

Comment: It's a possibility, but let's say "last resort" since they're still a way to alter the only sensible data. Just making a global autofit width undo the hide

Comment: Why is hiding the column you don't want your users to see a last resort? Seems like the first step?

Comment: Because of the un hide. But I may have found a workaround with the hidding and comments I test it... Hoping xls and xlsx work the same with comments and since i can protect comments alone... it won't cause excel to disallow me from deleting

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how named ranges help you.
Have you thought of adding Validation code to the workbook using the before save event, so that the user cannot save data that is not valid?
 Or seeing how much you can do using Excel's data validation rules.
Otherwise you have to read all the data and validate it later at DB update time (which is basically too late)
 Presumably the basic validation is that the iTemID is valid - your DB code won't care what order the data is in, and can skip empty rows etc.

Comment: I'm not directly in excel. Excel itself is not my problem, nor is my software importation feature. It's both together. In the past, they only used Excel and paper. At the first with our software, they could export data to Excel for visualization purpose. Recently, they ask to be able to "reimport data" they changed in the Excel file. So we need to keep trace of what is what. So we store the db pks formated rangename (sort issue) or another column (edit or interact issue). I try to find some hidden properties that will follow in case of sorting AND not being editable by user, not even viewable.